# Adding external xaml results in error NETSDK1022

Tags: wpf, xaml, csproj

In one of the projects I use Views located outside the project.

It's done like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="..\Desktop\Views\**\*.xaml" Link="Views\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    <Compile Include="..\Desktop\Views\**\*.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" Link="Views\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Everything worked as it should until 2 files with the same name appeared in the View folder in several subfolders:

```
 - Views
 - - View1
 - - - CustomView.xaml
 - - View2
 - - - CustomView.xaml
```

After this, an error appeared in the project
`error NETSDK1022: Duplicate 'Compile' items were included`

The reason is in the obj folder.
In my project it looks like this:

```
- obj
- - Debug
- - - net6.0...
- - - - CustomView.g.cs
- - - - CustomView.g.i.cs
```

It turns out that two CustomView.xaml are written to the same files, which leads to an error.

In a normal project, the obj directory should look like this:

```
- obj
- - Debug
- - - net6.0...
- - - - View1
- - - - - CustomView.g.cs
- - - - View2
- - - - - CustomView.g.i.cs
```